# JQuery UI: resizable div with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I made a resizable div and now I want a scrollbar (y-axis) when the user resized it too much. When there is enough space for the rows of text, the scrollbar should disappear. I thought this could be done with `overflow-y: auto` but it didn't.

**What it should look like**
[image]

**What it actually looks like**

https://jsfiddle.net/1wk4mevo/4/

As you can see, there is always a scrollbar even if there is enough space for all content in the div. How can I fix this? (code can be seen in the fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CSS for your handle.  If you drop the height from 7px to 0px the scrollbar goes away.  The element is within the box, so the 'extra' height is causing the scrollbar to appear at all times.

So, I tried removing the bottom:-5px; See below for a new fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/1wk4mevo/8/

Overriding this CSS works:

```
.ui-resizable-s {
    bottom:0px;   
}
```

And produces the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! and well explained :)